# how can I use eclipse to debug a libtool generated script?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, libtool

I have a large c++ project built with libtool. the problem is that eclipse will not run a libtool generated script, and I get a "Program is not a recognized executable." error message. how can I use eclipse debugger? I'm currently using kdevelop3 as an editor and debugging with insight.. which is horrible.

I could perhaps run the actual executable, thats in the ./libs of the project directory, but then I would have to manually set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and stuff like that... there must be a better way to so this.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: UPDATE: well, eventually I sqw no other option but setting all the environment variables myself (LD_LIBRARY_PATH and such) manually. this is of course a bad practice since these may change eventually, but i found no other way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running a script instead of an executable is still unsupported in Eclipse, see [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=328001). Until the feature is introduced, you cannot debug a libtool-enabled project under Eclipse unless you keep something like a

```
    path/to/configure --disable-shared
```

separate configuration, thus relying on static linking only for debugging purposes.

To do that, you

1. Open `Project|Properties` from the top menu
2. Select `Autotools|Configure Settings` from the left menu of the window
3. (Optionally) Create a new build configuration with a dedicated `C/C++ Build|Builder Settings|Build location`
4. Under `configure|Advanced`, fill the "Additional command-line options" with `--disable-shared`

Comment: Thanks, but than I still would have to specify the paths to the libraries myself, wouldn't I?

Comment: No you wouldn't, since they are statically linked. There are other disadvantages, of course: each time you change the library, you need to recompile the executables; in addition, the executables are pretty bloated.

Comment: Defeats one of the purposes of having libtool in the first place. +1 for a working solution though.

Answer (score 2):

You can work around it by running the actual executable instead of the libtool script. The executable will generally be found in `.libs/`. So in your debug configuration on the main tab set the value of `C/C++ Application` to something like `.libs/my_application`. Then all you'll need to do us update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` within your debug configuration.

Go to the environment tab of your debug configuration and make a new environment variable called `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You'll want to append the `.libs` directory to the path. So the value should look like this: `${project_loc}/.libs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` assuming your `.libs` folder is right inside of the project directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convince eclipse to start gdb like this:

```
$ libtool --mode=execute gdb <your-program>
```

See https://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/html_node/Debugging-executables.html

Comment: Yes, of course but how? iv'e tried many things including changing the debugger command line, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I think one could write a little wrapper program to interpose an exec of 'sh libtool --mode execute' to run gdb.  Call it 'gdb-libtool' and invoke that instead of gdb.

I am developing under both Windows and Linux so it's something I need for myself.

There are a few tricky bits, like getting the paths right at libtool and gdb invocation..  off to take a swat at that.

Cheers,  Jerry.

Comment: Nope : `Error creating session  Cannot run program "gdb-libtool": Unknown reason –`

Answer (score 1):

For the first point, you can disable intermediate libtool script by adding `-no-install` to `LDFLAGS` in your `Makefile.am` OR you can just run `make install` and debug from installed binary.

For the second point, you'll have to set and export your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` *before* launching eclipse.